# unable to install activemq-web-console in Fuse service mix

Tags: activemq-classic, apache-servicemix, fuseesb

"Error executing command: URL [mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-web-console/5.4.0/war] could not be resolved."

is thrown up when i do features:install activemq-web-console
i am using fuse 4.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removed the old Url for activemq from features:removeUrl  and added  the new one 
mvn:org.apache.activemq/activemq-karaf/5.4.0/xml/features

and re-installed activemq features . if u are unable to install mvn url's then,u must add the fuse repo's to your maven settings xml.
apart from this there is a well known bug

```
Add the following lines to etc/system.properties 




   webconsole.type=properties
   webconsole.jms.url=tcp://localhost:61616
   webconsole.jmx.url=service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/karaf-root
   webconsole.jmx.user=smx 
   webconsole.jmx.password=smx
```

this would make ur console work

Answer (score 0):

For newbie follow these steps:
1. list all features using following command:
   karaf@root> features:listurl
2. you can remove url using following command:
   features:removeurl

you can find the url to remove in the above removeurl command from the step 1 where you list urls.

1. add url that you want to using following command:
   features:addurl <>

and then follow steps that are mentioned by sanre6 above.