# Why does Activemq-web-console does not work on Fuse Servicemix 4.3.0-fuse-02-00?

Tags: java, activemq-classic, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I am unable to get activemq-web-console up and running after following instructions located at:
http://activemq.apache.org/osgi-integration.html
or
this thread:

> [unable to install activemq-web-console in Fuse service mix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652151/unable-to-install-activemq-web-console-in-fuse-service-mix)

In short, the steps I followed:
1) Fresh copy of Fuse Servicemix.
2) Install activemq-spring
3) create a new broker
4) Add web configuration settings to system.properties
4) Install war
5) Install activemq-web-console

Tried accessing:

> http://localhost:8181/activemqweb/

gives the stacktrace mentioned below.
Any help is appreciated.
Frankly, I do not understand what fuse is trying to do here. I was able to get the activemq-web-console on 4.3.0-00-00 but it doesn't work anymore in the newer version. I am not sure why additional bugs keep popping up. Sorry but I am just a little too frustrated right now.

> karaf@root> log:display-exception
>   javax.el.ELException: Error reading 'brokerName' on type org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade
>   at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:66)
>   at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.getValue(CompositeELResolver.java:53)
>   at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:118)
>   at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:186)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:925)
>   at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:75)
>   at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:374)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:342)
>   at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:267)
>   at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:806)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.jsp.JspServletWrapper$2.call(JspServletWrapper.java:132)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.jsp.JspServletWrapper$2.call(JspServletWrapper.java:127)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.swissbox.core.ContextClassLoaderUtils.doWithClassLoader(ContextClassLoaderUtils.java:60)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.jsp.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:124)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:83)
>   at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:76)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.SessionFilter.doFilter(SessionFilter.java:45)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.filter.ApplicationContextFilter.doFilter(ApplicationContextFilter.java:81)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.parsePage(PageFilter.java:118)
>   at com.opensymphony.module.sitemesh.filter.PageFilter.doFilter(PageFilter.java:52)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.internal.WelcomeFilesFilter.doFilter(WelcomeFilesFilter.java:169)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceServletHandler.handle(HttpServiceServletHandler.java:64)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.HttpServiceContext.handle(HttpServiceContext.java:111)
>   at org.ops4j.pax.web.service.jetty.internal.JettyServerHandlerCollection.handle(JettyServerHandlerCollection.java:68)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:547)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
>   at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
>   at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:409)
>   at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
>   Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Authentication failed
>   at org.apache.karaf.management.JaasAuthenticator.authenticate(JaasAuthenticator.java:69)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:213)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(RMIServerImpl.java:180)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.exceptionReceivedFromServer(StreamRemoteCall.java:255)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.StreamRemoteCall.executeCall(StreamRemoteCall.java:233)
>   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:142)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl_Stub.newClient(Unknown Source)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.getConnection(RMIConnector.java:2327)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnector.connect(RMIConnector.java:279)
>   at javax.management.remote.JMXConnectorFactory.connect(JMXConnectorFactory.java:248)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.createConnection(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:146)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.getMBeanServerConnection(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:114)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.getBrokerAdmin(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:88)
>   at org.apache.activemq.web.RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.getBrokerName(RemoteJMXBrokerFacade.java:101)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:62)
>   ... 44 more
>   Caused by: javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: User smx does not exist
>   at org.apache.karaf.jaas.modules.properties.PropertiesLoginModule.login(PropertiesLoginModule.java:104)
>   at org.apache.karaf.jaas.boot.ProxyLoginModule.login(ProxyLoginModule.java:83)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invoke(LoginContext.java:769)
>   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.access$000(LoginContext.java:186)
>   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext$4.run(LoginContext.java:683)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.invokePriv(LoginContext.java:680)
>   at javax.security.auth.login.LoginContext.login(LoginContext.java:579)
>   at org.apache.karaf.management.JaasAuthenticator.authenticate(JaasAuthenticator.java:66)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.doNewClient(RMIServerImpl.java:213)
>   at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIServerImpl.newClient(RMIServerImpl.java:180)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
>   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
>   at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:305)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:159)
>   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:155)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:535)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:790)
>   at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:649)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
>   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)

What is surprising is that I am able to verify smx:smx as the login credential for service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://localhost:1099/karaf-root using jconsole.

Answer (score 0):

1)Delete the space of the end of line.

> "webconsole.jmx.user=smx " -> "webconsole.jmx.user=smx"

2)Reboot Servicemix.

3)Try access.